# Branches of complex logarithmic function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Attach analytic branch of some complex logarithm function and find range (image) of set if possible

radius $\arg z =\pi /6$

positive $y$ axis

circle $|z|=1$

ring $3 \leq |z| \leq5$

I'm not sure how to start this but, $\log z=\ln r + i\theta$. And $\operatorname{Im} (\log z)=\theta$. Do I need to find $\log z$ for which $\operatorname{Im} (\log z)=\pi/6$ or i'm I completely lost.

radius $\arg z =\pi /6$ $\to$ $z=re^{i\pi/6}$

$$ \log z = \ln r + i \pi /6$$

Positive $y$ axis $\to$ $z=re^{i\pi/2}$
$$\log z=\ln r + i\pi /2$$

circle $|z|=1$ $\to$ $z=e^{i\theta}$
$$\log z=\ln 1+i\theta$$

ring $3 \leq |z| \leq5$ $\to$ $$\log z=\ln r + i\theta, \; \text{where}  3\leq r \leq 5$$
Did I get these correctly? critique?

Comment: The idea is to see what happens to the sets in question under the logarithm, i.e. if $z$ is in one of your sets, what form does $\log z$ have?

Comment: What you've done is correct. Now what about $+y$ axis?

Comment: What's the range thought?

Comment: I edited my post. Not sure I did those correctly I don't get the ring set.